# Restricted holonomy principle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, holonomy

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $M$ connected, $\nabla$  the Levi-Civita connection. The holonomy principle (see e.g. Besse "Einstein manifolds") states that there is a bijective correspondence between

1. Tensor fields $t$ invariant under parallel transport.
2. Parallel tensor fields, that is $\nabla t=0$.
3. Tensors at $x\in M$ invariant under the holonomy group of $M$.

[This entry](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parallel_field) of the Encyclopedia of Mathematics and my attempts at a proof seem to imply that 1. and 2. are always equivalent (1. $ \Rightarrow$ 2. is clear, I have some doubts about the reverse). **Is that true?**

So, suppose we replace holonomy with restricted holonomy in 3.  I think 1. would become the statement that if $\gamma$, $\delta$ are homotopic curves then parallel trasport along $\gamma $ is equal to parallel transport along $\delta$. **What happens to 2.?**

EDIT I am getting more and more convinced that 2. does not imply 1. in the non-simply connected case. Consider $\pi: S^2 \to RP^2$ with the metric on $RP^2$ induced from the round metric on $S^2$. If $\gamma$ is a geodesic of $S^2$ such that $\pi\circ \gamma$ is non-contractible, then the tangent to $\pi\circ\gamma$ is a parallel vector field along $\pi \circ\gamma$, but parallel transport along $\pi\circ \gamma$ acts as minus the identity.

If anyone could provide a proof of the fact that vanishing covariant derivative implies that parallel transport is homotopy invariant, or whatever is the correct statement, and which does not use the Ambrose-Singer theorem, that would be great!

Comment: What is your definition of a tensor parallel along a curve?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I would say that $T$ is parallel along $\gamma$ if  $\nabla_{\dot\gamma} T\circ\gamma=0$. But I see I was confused in my edit, being parallel along a specific curve is a much weaker condition than being parallel.